# grabbing data from a string with regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I could use some help writing a regex to select only the "X" in between the hard brackets. The information is in a text file and I can each line will be its own string.

```
1.[ ]: Build a blanket fort
2.[X]: Eat a pancake
53.[X]: Change the sheets
4.[ ]: Make a model airplane
10.[X]: FizzBuzz
```

Comment: Is the `X` literal or a variable for anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern `.*\[(.*?)\].*` should suit your needs (note escaping of the brackets) and put whatever is between the brackets in the first/only match group.

e.g. `'2.[X]: Eat a pancake'.match('.*\[(.*?)\].*')[1]` will return `X` and `'4.[ ]: Make a model airplane'.match('.*\[(.*?)\].*')[1]` will return a space.

If you don't want any matches returned if there is no X (or whatever) replace the `.*?` in brackets with what you would like to match, like `.*\[([A-Z]*)\].*` if you're only expecting a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
line = '53.[X]: Change the sheets'

if line.include? '[X]'
  puts 'This answer was selected'
end
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer but in my case, though not stated above, the string could also contain an X somewhere else, thus I need to grab the one between the hard brackets

Comment: @LowellMower, I edited a couple of times. I don't know which version you saw, but the last version does what you want.